# Teaching git while keeping it 'as easy as svn'

Tags: git, svn

I am at University and my group is starting a programming project together.

In a previous subject we were taught the basics of svn and how to commit, as well as how to use Toitosesvn. We were told not to worry about branching (and so not taught about it) since it was a fairly small program. During the project the svn server went down, leaving everybody unable to work, however people don't think much of it.

For this project, I am pushing to have a DVCS. After explaining how git differs from svn, they said it would be OK, but want it to be as easy as using svn. Since we will be using Eclipse^ they just want instructions on how to use git with Eclipse. (I plan on using [EGit](http://www.eclipse.org/egit/))

Since we were not taught about it, branching is a foreign concept to the rest of the group members. However, due to the new concepts in git (for example, branching) how to use the GUI is not the only thing that needs to be taught.

How do I introduce the concepts of git in a way that is easy for svn developers used to the gui?

Note: Git is being used because I am pushing it and I know it (and don't know mercurial or bazaar)

^: We will be building an android program.

Comment: This is absolutely not going to be what you want to hear, but: 1) forget whatever you learned about SVN, the terminology is similar to git but with different enough meaning to be confusing. 2) EGit is really bad. At least, last year it was. I doubt it got much better. It breaks in weird and random ways, it doesn't support submodules, etc. You'll be better off using git from the command line.

Comment: Different question.  How do you teach git in such a way that anyone would think it is more difficult than svn?

Comment: what about "Git - SVN Crash Course" http://git.or.cz/course/svn.html? git based on your svn knowledge.

Comment: @GGG No GUI may just mean those in my group will probably just say "lets just use svn as it works and has a GUI" since they are Windows and Mac users

Comment: @Portablejim if these guys are developers, they can handle it. Hell, I've got graphic designers checking their work in via command-line git. Granted, they don't really need any advanced functionality... If your guys need a GUI, there's git-gui/gitk, tortoise, etc. And EGit. But EGit is junk, I promise.

Comment: @GGG They don't want to go to the effort to learn something new (stick with what they know and were taught). They even think that as one section is very small, it does not really need version control.

Comment: @Portablejim and these are *students*? This is how 60-something year old men who have been writing COBOL for the last four decades are supposed to act, not students. Let the instructor know that the rest of the group is useless (in as nice a way as possible) and ask to complete the project alone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few notes:

- **[Git Ready](http://gitready.com/)** is a good, gentle introduction to Git.
- I also like the visual nature of [**Git for Computer Scientists**](http://eagain.net/articles/git-for-computer-scientists/).
- Git is not really analogous to Subversion. Trying to draw analogies between the two of them is probably just going to confuse the mental model your teammates will need to work in git.

On a side note, I wouldn't push your teammates too hard to use a technology they're unfamiliar with. There is a right time and a wrong time to introduce technology, and on the limited horizon of a programming project, learning how to use a DVCS may not be the way to go. Part of being a good developer is knowing when *not* to fight some battles.

Ultimately, git is a great enhancement to productivity, but not if it comes at the cost of slowing everything else down for your team.

Comment: I like "git for computer scientists" a lot too.  It's pretty brief though and does not do much for telling you about the command set.

Answer (score 2):

Mercurial might actually be easier, because it is more automatic.  You can think of Hg as "git without an index", with all that this implies. :-)  Hg also forbids history rewriting, which has its good and bad points; in particular, it means you need add-ons like queues for people to supply patches to each other during development.

All that aside, I'd actually lean towards git myself, in part because it "works right" even though the user interface is tremendously complex.  If you get people started with git 1.7.x they can generally just remember "git commit -a".

Comment: if it "works right", we hadn't such giant heap of question around git-troubleshooting, as we have - now here!

Comment: Heh.  That's because the UI and terminology are ... "not the best", shall we say? :-)

Comment: We have more deep troubles here visible, than terminology and GUI. I consider they as *disadvantages of architecture*

Comment: Those "disadvantages" are more often than not just "differences", and often end up being strengths.  The index, for example, lets me more easily split changes up into logical groups and commit each group separately.  Hg, by not separating the working copy and the index, makes that harder.

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: Nohow

---

In order to avoid all sharp corners you have to forgot about

- Branches
- Walks in history
- Many remotes (thus - **D**-VCS nature)

Un this case you have almost nothing from VCS per se

BTW, Subversion background for Git-newcomers is more minus, than plus

- [Git-terminology](http://git.661346.n2.nabble.com/Git-terminology-remote-add-track-stage-etc-td5648599.html) is at least annoying and unclean (GUI **does not hide** basic concepts)
- Git-jargon and its [refusal to use conventional revision control terminology](http://algorithm.com.au/blog/files/git-svn-and-subversion.php)

"Git-SVN Crash Course" helps some way, but **does not solve all troubles fully**

PS: Maybe cross-platform SmartGit can make Git-life more easier

Answer (score 0):

You may install SubGit (subgit.com) on the SVN server. After that the server will get 2 interfaces: SVN and Git. I mean, if you push to the Git repository, the changes will be translated to the SVN repository automatically; and vice-versa.

It preserves main concepts of Subversion like ignore, EOLs-management, tags, merges and so on (much better than git-svn does).